# Questions PHP Images into Bootstrap Thumbnails show

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

Help i uses this code PHP and bootstrap  please see image.

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM article ORDER BY article_id DESC";
$r = page_query($link, $sql, 10);
while ($a = mysqli_fetch_array($r)) {
  $src = "images/cover-image.jpg";
  if ($a['image_id'] != 0) {
    $src = "read-image.php?id={$a['image_id']}";
  }
  echo '  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <div class="thumb">
          <img src="' . $src . '" alt="">
          <div class="caption-overflow">
            <span>
              <a href="' . $src . '" data-popup="lightbox" class="btn border-white text-white btn-flat btn-icon btn-rounded"><i class="icon-plus3"></i></a>
              <a href="#" class="btn border-white text-white btn-flat btn-icon btn-rounded ml-5"><i class="icon-link2"></i></a>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="caption">
          <h6 class="no-margin-top text-semibold">
            <a href="#" class="text-default">Not rapturous</a> 
            <a href="#" class="text-muted"><i class="icon-download pull-right"></i></a>
          </h6>
          ' . mb_substr($a['article_text'], 0, 120, 'utf-8') . '...<br>' . ' 
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>';
  }

if (page_total() > 1) {
  echo '<p id="page">';
  page_echo_pagenums();
  echo '</p>';
}
?>
```

**Image**

[image]

I use this code PHP and bootstrap  see images
The problem of this sort on the part of the how to had to modify how it displays the correct result.

Comment: Am I the only one who doesn't know what the question is about? Edit: I guess I'm the only one in here *lol* (not for long, bye bye).

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm with you.. not a clue.. OP can you please make the issue more clear.

Answer (score 0):

What I found Is:

1. You opened `<div class="row">`. But, not closed. (It may be one of the reason for alignment not coming properly)
2. And, My suggestion is not to use `<div class="row">` inside `while` loop. Place it above `while` loop. Because every occurrence in while loop, it will take single `row` as whole div. Putting it before `while` loop, it will help you to place all `col-lg-3` rows inside `<div class="row">` in proper alignment.

**Updated Code:**

```
<div class="row">
  <?php
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM article ORDER BY article_id DESC";
  $r = page_query($link, $sql, 10);
  while ($a = mysqli_fetch_array($r)) {
    $src = "images/cover-image.jpg";
    if ($a['image_id'] != 0) {
      $src = "read-image.php?id={$a['image_id']}";
    }
    echo '  
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <div class="thumb">
            <img src="' . $src . '" alt="">
            <div class="caption-overflow">
              <span>
                <a href="' . $src . '" data-popup="lightbox" class="btn border-white text-white btn-flat btn-icon btn-rounded"><i class="icon-plus3"></i></a>
                <a href="#" class="btn border-white text-white btn-flat btn-icon btn-rounded ml-5"><i class="icon-link2"></i></a>
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="caption">
            <h6 class="no-margin-top text-semibold">
              <a href="#" class="text-default">Not rapturous</a> 
              <a href="#" class="text-muted"><i class="icon-download pull-right"></i></a>
            </h6>
            ' . mb_substr($a['article_text'], 0, 120, 'utf-8') . '...<br>' . ' 
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>';
    }
  ?>
</div>
```

When, I did these changes in my desktop. It works fine for me. Keep calm. Have patience. And, Try once again. It will work.